# ASP.Net MVC List action returning Json Data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where-in I am trying to use the jQuery template plugin for displaying list of data on my MVC list view. However my list is the default view of my mvc application. I want to use the same action to server both purposes of returning json data as well as returning view.

It is making double trip for getting data. Is there a way that as soon as my action is called, I return Json data and use the template plugin to display data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if the action has been called with AJAX then return JSON data and if not return a normal view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = FetchModel();
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Of course this `if` makes your controller action ugly. It would be far better to use action filters to avoid repeating this logic in multiple actions:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
            if (viewResult != null)
            {
                if (viewResult.Model != null)
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                    {
                        Data = viewResult.Model,
                        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then decorate your controller with this attribute:

```
[MyFilter]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = FetchModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this still will have 2 round trips to server which I want to avoid. I want to return just the Json data via my List action and display it via template plugin. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Your comment to Darins great answer leads me to believe you need the following which your question does not really explain.

If I have not crossed my wires then this my help...

You can return a html view but also include a script tag that includes a json object.

Create a toJson html helper extension e.g

```
  public static class MvcViewExtensions 
  {

    public static string toJson(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, object obj)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
    }
  }
```

Then in you view something like this

```
<html>

    ...other html stuff

    <script>

        var json = <%= Html.ToJson(Model.someProperty) %>;
        //call to some js to do your templating
        myapp.someTemplatingFunc(json);

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I am trying the same above code with Razor syntax which is failing. I am trying as:

var json = @Model.ToJson();

Comment: well 'failing' is not much use to me - have you got more info? Has the Model got a ToJson method?

Comment: No. I have a separate static class for ToJson as mentioned by you above. However as soon as the compiler hits @Model.ToJson(), it throws error "'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyNameSpace.Models.MyClass>' does not contain a definition for 'ToJson'"

Comment: Well the extension method is added to the html helper not to the model object. Notice the Html.ToJson rather than Model.ToJson

Comment: I tried your method too with the following syntax: @Html.ToJson((List<MyNamespace.Models.MyClass>)Model); which gives me javascript error "Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 64
Char: 18
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/MyWebApplication/"

Comment: @redsquare - The issue is resolved. I did the changes as @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))); and it works like a charm. Thanks for all your help.